# Componente se renderiza 5 veces reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Estoy intentando hacer una especie de carrito de compras con json server (como api) pero cuando intento hacer la funcionalidad de carrito y de añadir el producto al mismo este renderiza 5 veces el hook del producto y los dos primeros renders son undefined y los 3 siguientes si contienen la información que estoy pasando.

Comparto los codigos:

1. App.js

```
    import React from "react";
    import { Route } from "wouter";
    
    import Header from "./components/Header";
    import Productlist from "./components/Productlist";
    import Product from "./pages/Product";
    import Cart from "./components/Cart";
    import "./App.css";
    
    import { CartContextProvider } from "./context/CartContext";
    
    function App() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Header />
                <Route path="/productos" component={Productlist} />
                <Route path="/productos/:id" component={Product} />
                <CartContextProvider>
                    <Route path="/cart" component={Cart} />
                </CartContextProvider>
            </div>
        );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

2. El context

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    
    const CartContext = React.createContext({});
    
    export function CartContextProvider({ children }) {
        const [producto, setProducto] = useState([]);
        return (
            <CartContext.Provider value={{ producto, setProducto }}>
                {children}
            </CartContext.Provider>
        );
    }
    
    export default CartContext;
```

3. El hook del producto donde busca en la api

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getProductById } from "../services/api";

export function useProduct(id) {
    const [item, setItem] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await getProductById(id);
            setItem(response);
            console.log(response);
        };

        fetchData();
    }, [id]);

    return { item };
}
```

4. Finalmente el componente producto que se renderiza 4 veces (2 undefined y 3 con los datos correctos)

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { useProduct } from "../hooks/useProduct";
import CartContext from "../context/CartContext";
import "./Product.css";

export default function Product({ params }) {
    const { producto, setProducto } = useContext(CartContext);
    const { item } = useProduct(params.id);
    **console.log(item);**

    const addCartHandler = (e) => {
        setProducto({ ...producto, item });
    };

    return (
        <div className="App__item">
            <h3 className="App__item--title">{item.name}</h3>
            <span className="App__item--stock">
                {item.stock} unidades disponibles
            </span>
            <p className="App__item--desc">
                Pequeña descripción del producto, ya que es impresionante y hay
                que venderlo!
            </p>
            <button onClick={addCartHandler} className="App__item--add">
                Añadir
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Al tirar un `console.log` de los valores obtenidos en el custom hook (useProduct) dentro del componente Product, recibo 5 valores:

[image: Dos valores vienen como]

Muchas gracias por su ayuda!!!

Comment: No es clara tu pregunta, considera editarla y explicar claramente el punto del problema

Comment: ya pude solucionar el problema que se presentaba. Todo era porque estaba realizando la interacción de la API dentro del useEffect, lo que generaba dos llamadas asyncronas indenifidas, pero al sacar la interacción y solo hacer un call se solucionó: `const fetchData = async () => {const response = await getProductById(id); setItem(response); } useEffect(() => {fetchData();
    }, [id]);`